# Finish android activity via Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, activity-finish

I'm currently working on an Android Application using Phonegap/Cordova.
I need to finish the current activity and go back to the previously active activity/app.

Is there an easy way to call the `finish()` method (of the Activity class) from my Javascript code using Cordova?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On Android, You can use `navigator.app.exitApp()`